# Event function not working

Tags: knockout.js

I have a button which binds to an event function:

```thml
<button type="button" data-bind="event: { click: deleteWrapper},
   attr: {'data-wrapper': wrapper_id}">Delete</button>
```

In the js file (which is written using jQuery and Knockout) I have an observable variable like this:

```
isChecked: ko.observable(false)
```

and the `deleteWrapper` function:

```
deleteWrapper: function(data, event) {
    var self = this;
    var clickedId = event.target.getAttribute('data-wrapper');
},
```

When I alert out the `clickedId` or an arbitrary string, it's okay, but when I want to alert the value of `isChecked`:

```
alert(self.isChecked());
```

It doesn't show anything. I tried with other `observable` and `observableArray`, which did not work either. However, when I tried the exact same thing with other functions, it worked. Is there something wrong with the event function?

Comment: But could you show the code where is isChecked defined?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: It's `isChecked: ko.observable(false)`. This syntax may seems strange since my code is written for Magento

Comment: With `var self = this;` in your `deleteWrapper` you are hiding the `self` which is declared outside of your function. Just remove the `var self = this;` and `alert(self.isChecked());` should work fine.

Comment: thanks, I'll see if that works out

Comment: @HauPham I understand, but in order to make it work, you have to make sure the isChecked is rightly bound to the same view model that is being used for the event handler. It's not really clear how things are linked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yikes! Don't mix Knockout and jQuery like that. Knockout is an MVVM library, and you should not need jQuery and `data-` attributes like that.

Here's how to do it in Knockout:

```js
var item1 = { name: "Item ONE", isChecked: ko.observable(false) };
var item2 = { name: "Item TWO", isChecked: ko.observable(true) };
var item3 = { name: "Item THREE", isChecked: ko.observable(false) };

var rootViewModel = {
  items: ko.observableArray([item1, item2, item3])
};

rootViewModel.deleteWrapper = function(item) {
  alert(item.isChecked());
  rootViewModel.items.remove(item);
};

ko.applyBindings(rootViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked">
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: $root.deleteWrapper">Delete</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The gist of this solution:

- Have a function to handle deletes on the *parent* view model;
- That function gets the contextual `$data` (i.e. an item) as an argument;
- Have *all* logic inside your view models (where you can unit test it);
- Keep your view "dumb", merely reflecting the latest state of the view models;

I also recommend using constructor functions or a similar pattern to simplify the way your view models work.

---

PS. As a footnote, if you *insist* on following the route you've chosen, here's how to do it:

```js
var item1 = { wrapper_id: 1, name: "Item ONE", isChecked: ko.observable(false) };
var item2 = { wrapper_id: 2, name: "Item TWO", isChecked: ko.observable(true) };
var item3 = { wrapper_id: 3, name: "Item THREE", isChecked: ko.observable(false) };

var rootViewModel = {
  items: ko.observableArray([item1, item2, item3])
};

rootViewModel.deleteWrapper = function(data, event) {
  var id = $(event.target).data("wrapper");
  
  // This will be the same as "data" argument
  var item = rootViewModel.items().filter(function(i) { return i.wrapper_id == id; })[0];
  
  rootViewModel.items.remove(item);
};

ko.applyBindings(rootViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked">
    <button data-bind="event: { click: $root.deleteWrapper }, attr: { 'data-wrapper': wrapper_id }">Delete</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

As a final footnote, I've incorporated [@RoyJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34722864/419956)'s simplification (removing with `remove` instead of `splice`) as well.

Answer (score 1):

In ko you can attach directly the click event to a function with the [click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html), like this:

```
<button type="button" data-bind="click: deleteWrapper
```

I suppose it's a typo, but you must specify the function name without prefixing it with `$` (just as shown above).

The function that handles the ko event, in this case `deleteWrapper`, [receives the model value in the context of the bound element as first parameter](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-1-passing-a-current-item-as-a-parameter-to-your-handler-function). So your function should look like this:

```
deleteWrapper: function(data) {
    /* data is the data bound to the button */
    var clickedId = data.wrapper_id;
},
```

I don't know what you want to do with the `deleteWrapper` function, but you can directly access the bound data from the received parameter as shown above.

Neither I know where you're trying to run this code: `alert(self.isChecked());` but, provided `self` is really the object to which `isChecked()` belongs to, this should work.

Comment: Hau Pham, I've answered your question even although there is missing information. If uou want to clarify something else after seeing my answer, please, edit your question and leave me a comment, so that I can improve my answer. The questions should include the whole code necessary to undesrtand and reproduce the problem. For example saying "When I alert out the clickedId or an arbitrary string, it's okay, but when I want to alert out the value of isChecked..." means nothing, unless you show the related code, i.e. where is this done?

Comment: Thanks, and by the way, $ was a typo indeed

Answer (score 0):

I simplified JotaBe's second solution by using observableArray's `remove` method.

```js
var item1 = { wrapper_id: 1, name: "Item ONE", isChecked: ko.observable(false) };
var item2 = { wrapper_id: 2, name: "Item TWO", isChecked: ko.observable(true) };
var item3 = { wrapper_id: 3, name: "Item THREE", isChecked: ko.observable(false) };

var rootViewModel = {
  items: ko.observableArray([item1, item2, item3])
};

rootViewModel.deleteWrapper = function(data) {
  rootViewModel.items.remove(data);
};

ko.applyBindings(rootViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked">
    <button data-bind="event: { click: $root.deleteWrapper }, attr: { 'data-wrapper': wrapper_id }">Delete</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```